# Any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL_2(p)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $SL_2(p)$. Is this true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL_2(p)$ has order $p$ and so does a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $SL_2(p)$. Does this mean that $Syl_p(GL_2(p)) = Syl_p(SL_2(p))$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally if $N \unlhd G$ and $[G:N]$ is relatively prime to $p$, then the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$ and $G$ are the same. This handles your case, since $\operatorname{SL}_2(p) \unlhd \operatorname{GL}_2(p)$ (being the kernel of the determinant homomorphism) and $[\operatorname{GL}_2(p):\operatorname{SL}_2(p)]=p-1$ (from the first isomorphism theorem) is relatively prime to $p$.

#### Proof of the generalization:

If $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$, then $P$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ just because $[G:N]$ is relatively prime to $p$ (so the same power of $p$ divides both $|G|$ and $|B|$). If $Q$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then Sylow's theorem says $P$ and $Q$ are conjugate, so $P^g = Q$ for some $g \in G$. Then $Q = P^g \leq N^g = N$ as long as $N \unlhd G$. Hence every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, and every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$. $\square$

#### Smallest such $N$:

There is a unique smallest such normal subgroup $N$. It is called $O^{p'}(G)$ and is the intersection of all normal subgroups whose index is relatively prime to $p$. It is also the subgroup generated by the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

#### Counterexample:

If you don't require $N$ to be normal, then there may be Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ that are not Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$. The smallest example is $G=S_3$, a non-abelian group of order $6$. Take $H=S_2=\langle (1,2) \rangle$ and $p=2$. Then $|G|$ and $|H|$ are divisible by the same power of $p$, so their Sylow $p$-subgroups have the same size. Every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ is therefore a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ (there is only one, $H$ itself). However, $G$ has two other Sylow $p$-subgroups: $\langle (1,3) \rangle$ and $\langle(2,3) \rangle$, neither of which is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ (because they are not even subgroups of $H$).

Comment: Great post for that generalization. +1

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $|SL_2(p)|=p(p^2-1)$ and $|GL_2(p)|=p(p^2-1)(p-1)$.

Any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $SL_2(p)$ has order $p$ and, hence, is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $GL_2(p)$.

On the other hand, $UT_2(p)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL_2(p)$. Then (i) $UT_2(p) < SL_2(p)$; and (ii) $S^{-1}UT_2(p)S < SL_2(p)$ for any $S \in GL_2(p)$. Thus, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL_2(p)$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup in $SL_2(p)$.

**Update**: Here $UT_2(p)$ is the group of upper triangular matrices, s.t. all elements on the main diagonal are 1.

Comment: What is $UT_2(p)$?

Comment: Exactly my thought: $\; UT_2(p)\;$ is not a/the best well-known notation for the subgroup of unipotent matrices = upper triangular matrices all of which main diagonal's entries are $\;1\;$ = matrices $\;A\;$ s.t. $\;A-I\;$ is nilpotent. +1

Comment: Aah.. I see. So since $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\a & 1\end{array}\right) \in SL_2(p)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL_2(p)$ and $A^S \in SL_2(p)$ for every $S\in Syl_p(GL_2(p))$ then of course every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL_2(p)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $SL_2(p)$.

Comment: $a\in \mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: Thanks, @DonAntonio. I updated my post. Indeed, this notation is not a standard one.